# Allocation free delegate or other way to call method by address?

Tags: c#, delegates, mono, function-pointers

I need to be able to call a single method based on a function pointer in C# using Mono. Delegates work fine for this and it's their purpose, but they seem to allocate 52 bytes each time I set the delegate (not +=, but just setting it using = so there's always one and only one method referenced by the delegate).

This delegate changes many times per second and it causes the GC to kick in periodically which I'd like to avoid.

I don't mind the initial memory allocation, but is there a way to prevent an allocation each time I change the single delegate value?

If not, is there any other dynamic way to call a method in C# besides delegates that wouldn't allocate any memory each time the address is changed?

Comment: the fact that the delegate is changing so often seems to suggest that your barking up the wrong tree with your design, maybe. Isn't the answer, not *how do I stop my delegate using so much memory* but more, *how do I stop the delegate having to change so often*?

Comment: Can you post more detail on why you're changing delegates all the time? There might be an alternative.

Comment: I do find the actual question quite interesting. Wonder if there is a way to prevent allocations for delegates

Comment: I have a bunch of state machines for games. To make the state machine easy to manage and upgrade it uses a single delegate to branch states instead of a giant switch/case statement. Also allows the state machines to be divided up into multiple files for easier maintenance. Hundreds of actors in the world running around at 60 frames per second and all using state machines causes hundreds of small 52 byte allocations which then every second or so the GC kicks in and causes hiccups.

Comment: What about utilizing an interface and letting polymorphism do its thing... ?

Comment: What I mean by the above.. is that if you have an object that represents each state and pass it in to the update method of each actor.. you essentially have a single object for each state (plus an allocation for a reference)

Comment: @ServéLaurijssen http://blogs.msdn.com/b/shawnhar/archive/2007/07/09/delegates-events-and-garbage.aspx?Redirected=true  `It is actually impossible to construct a new delegate without allocating memory`

Comment: Clearly you are trying to solve the wrong problem.  Your game doesn't look any smoother when it hiccups once every 10 seconds instead of once every 1 second.  Use a generational garbage collector, one that collects short-lived objects, like these delegates, in less than a hundred microseconds.  Mono didn't used to have done, pretty sure it does now.

Comment: Mono in Unity doesn't have sgen. And anyway, we're getting off-topic. I'm well aware of architecture solutions. My question is whether delegates are the only way to call a method, and if there's anything that can be done to reuse the boxed pointer so it doesn't keep creating new ones.

Comment: Generational garbage collection is also costing valuable time. Nothing is for free. You cannot expect to write code with lots of small allocs and then have those objects magically get collected at little performance impact. In game development, if you can avoid frequent alloc, you should avoid frequent alloc. Garbage collector tuning / replacement should be the last resort.

Answer (score 17):

Any code you write like this

```
Action action = foo.DoSomething;
```

Ends up being compiled into this

```
Action action = new Action(foo.DoSomething);
```

Which is where the allocations are coming from. There aren't any perfect ways around this but to prevent the allocations you need to cache and reuse the delegate.

### Implementation Side Fix

You could achieve this on the implementation side by creating a delegate for each of your methods.

```
public class Foo
{
    public void DoSomething() { /*nop*/ }

    private Action _doSomethingDelegate;
    public Action DoSomethingDelegate
    {
        get { return _doSomethingDelegate ?? (_doSomethingDelegate = DoSomething); }
    }
}
```

Then you would just reference the existing delegate rather than the method

```
Action action = foo.DoSomethingDelegate;
```

### Cache Fix

Another option is to use some sort of cache class but this introduces a whole pile of object lifetime issues which you probably don't want in a game scenario. This is a bit of a crude implementation are real one would probably want to use weak references.

```
public static class DelegateCache
{
    private static readonly Dictionary<object, Dictionary<string, Delegate>> Cache = new Dictionary<object, Dictionary<string, Delegate>>();

    private static Dictionary<string, Delegate> GetObjectCache(object instance)
    {
        Dictionary<string, Delegate> delegates;
        if (!Cache.TryGetValue(instance, out delegates))
        {
            Cache[instance] = delegates = new Dictionary<string, Delegate>();
        }
        return delegates;
    }

    public static T GetDelegate<T>(object instance, string method)
        where T: class
    {
        var delegates = GetObjectCache(instance);
        Delegate del;
        if (!delegates.TryGetValue(method, out del))
        {
            delegates[method] = del = Delegate.CreateDelegate(typeof(T), instance, method);
        }
        return del as T;
    }
}
```

Using this would then look like this

```
Action action = DelegateCache.GetDelegate<Action>(foo, "DoSomething");
```

### Summary

Running some tests both these methods have only a single allocation per object/method pair. I would probably go the implementation side fix it is a lot cleaner even though it is a lot of work. If there are a lot of methods and you plan on adding many more you could use T4 to generate a partial class with the delegate implementation for your methods.