# How can I tell from this C# JIT assembly that I am not creating an object

Tags: c#

Suppose we have this, and I've added a comment on the area I am checking. This is with whatever the latest .NET is at the time of writing (5 or 6).

My goal is to avoid the GC by not having any `Action`s getting created under me. I am okay with garbage, but I can't have something spewing out tons of garbage when I call functions many times because they generate unacceptable GC pauses. However, maybe the JIT is smart enough to bypass the object creation completely.

To investigate, I made this program to see if `new Action(...)` is being generated or not:

```
using System;

public class ClassWithMethod
{
    public void MethodToCall() 
    {
        Console.WriteLine("hi");
    }
}

public class Program
{
    private ClassWithMethod instance = new ClassWithMethod();
    
    private void Call(Action action)
    {
        action();
    }
    
    public void DoStuff()
    {
        Call(instance.MethodToCall);  // <=== THIS LINE
    }
    
    public static void Main()
    {
        Program program = new Program();
        program.DoStuff();
    }
}
```

It generates the following intermediate code

```
; Core CLR 5.0.721.25508 on amd64

ClassWithMethod..ctor()
    L0000: ret

ClassWithMethod.MethodToCall()
    L0000: mov rcx, 0x2d94b437fc8
    L000a: mov rcx, [rcx]
    L000d: jmp System.Console.WriteLine(System.String)

Program..ctor()
    L0000: push rsi
    L0001: sub rsp, 0x20
    L0005: mov rsi, rcx
    L0008: mov rcx, 0x7ffaf463cd50
    L0012: call 0x00007ffb4be79b70
    L0017: lea rcx, [rsi+8]
    L001b: mov rdx, rax
    L001e: call 0x00007ffb4be79780
    L0023: nop
    L0024: add rsp, 0x20
    L0028: pop rsi
    L0029: ret

Program.Call(System.Action)
    L0000: mov rcx, [rdx+8]
    L0004: mov rax, [rdx+0x18]
    L0008: jmp rax

Program.DoStuff()
    L0000: push rdi
    L0001: push rsi
    L0002: sub rsp, 0x28
    L0006: mov rsi, rcx
    L0009: mov rcx, 0x7ffaec4c4288
    L0013: call 0x00007ffb4be79b70
    L0018: mov rdi, rax
    L001b: mov rdx, [rsi+8]
    L001f: test rdx, rdx
    L0022: je short L004c
    L0024: lea rcx, [rdi+8]
    L0028: call 0x00007ffb4be79780
    L002d: mov rcx, ClassWithMethod.MethodToCall()
    L0037: mov [rdi+0x18], rcx
    L003b: mov rcx, [rdi+8]
    L003f: mov rax, [rdi+0x18]
    L0043: add rsp, 0x28
    L0047: pop rsi
    L0048: pop rdi
    L0049: jmp rax
    L004c: call System.MulticastDelegate.ThrowNullThisInDelegateToInstance()
    L0051: int3

Program.Main()
    L0000: push rsi
    L0001: sub rsp, 0x20
    L0005: mov rcx, 0x7ffaf463d0a0
    L000f: call 0x00007ffb4be79b70
    L0014: mov rsi, rax
    L0017: mov rcx, 0x7ffaf463cd50
    L0021: call 0x00007ffb4be79b70
    L0026: lea rcx, [rsi+8]
    L002a: mov rdx, rax
    L002d: call 0x00007ffb4be79780
    L0032: mov rcx, rsi
    L0035: add rsp, 0x20
    L0039: pop rsi
    L003a: jmp Program.DoStuff()
```

Now the IL viewer shows

```
.method public hidebysig 
    instance void DoStuff () cil managed 
{
    // Method begins at RVA 0x206c
    // Code size 24 (0x18)
    .maxstack 8

    IL_0000: ldarg.0
    IL_0001: ldarg.0
    IL_0002: ldfld class ClassWithMethod Program::'instance'
    IL_0007: ldftn instance void ClassWithMethod::MethodToCall()
    IL_000d: newobj instance void [System.Private.CoreLib]System.Action::.ctor(object, native int)
    IL_0012: call instance void Program::Call(class [System.Private.CoreLib]System.Action)
    IL_0017: ret
} // end of method Program::DoStuff
```

This line from the above

```
IL_000d: newobj instance void [System.Private.CoreLib]System.Action::.ctor(object, native int)
```

seems to imply that a new `Action` object is being made. For me, this is *very bad*.

However, I cannot tell if object creation is happening in the JIT version.

There is this line

```
L0028: call 0x00007ffb4be79780
```

I am unsure if this is referencing a constructor and the JIT is not eliding object creation by going straight to the delegate, or if this is in fact doing it. How can I tell?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Allocation free delegate or other way to call method by address?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20837187/allocation-free-delegate-or-other-way-to-call-method-by-address)

Comment: @PeterB Thanks, though it is something I already could do yet am explicitly trying to not do. That link would be adding a non-zero complexity and messing up my code which may not be necessary if the JIT does what I am investigating. My question related to JIT assembly remains unanswered and I do not learn anything if this is unanswered. Also that question has nothing to do with JIT assembly so it is very divorced from what my question is aiming at, and an approaching-decade-old-answer could arguably be very outdated and wrong by now. In short, good intentions appreciated but it does not help.

Comment: You can check these things with a memory profiler.

Comment: @TheGeneral Where can I find a free memory profiler that will give me answer?

Comment: Use [Clr Heap Allocation Analyzer](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=MukulSabharwal.ClrHeapAllocationAnalyzer) - it will issue a warning on your sample code: "This will allocate a delegate instance"

Comment: @TheGeneral I realize I've made a mistake. By me going with your recommendation for a memory profiler I am not learning how to answer this question. I should not have asked where to find one because it deprives me of learning what I am interested in, which is what the JIT assembly is doing. If I check with a memory profiler, sure I may answer the question, but my knowledge is not augmented at all.